# can i add rake task to my rails app by making gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I want to add original rake task to my rails app by making gem. But, I couldn't.
Please tell me my mistake.

In my gem file

```
>lib/gem_test.rb
require "gem_test/version"
require 'gem_test/railtie' if defined?(Rails) && Rails.version >= "3"
module GemTest
  #this is dummy method for loading check
  def self.hogehoge
    "hogehoge"
  end
end

>lib/gem_test/railtie.rb
module GemTest
   class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
     rake_tasks do
       load "tasks/gem_test.rake"
     end
   end
end

>lib/tasks/gem_test.rake
namespace :fugafuga do
  desc "fugafuga"
  task :piyopiyo do
    puts "piyopoyo"
  end
end
```

and, Gemfile in my rails app,`gem gem_test, git:mygitrepository`. But I don't find `fugafuga:piyopiyo`task in result of `rake -T`.

If need more infomation, see [my repository](https://github.com/lastcat/gem_test)

Answer (score -1):

I think you must require rake in your rakefile:

```
namespace :fugafuga do

  require 'rake' <----

  desc "fugafuga"
  task :piyopiyo do
    puts "piyopoyo"
  end

end
```